# .net app call hierarchy explorer?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any shortcut or mechanism to visualize the call hierarchy of an entire .net app? That means the method to and from call all in a single screen, similar to DBML window that visualizes the relationships. I know the call hierarchy of Visual Studio .net, and is a bit lazy to set debugger and navigate through the entire app. As the app is itself a very big project and I need its visual representation.

Any third party app is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate call graphs with RedGate's [ANTS Performance profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)... this shows you the calls that were made during a period of execution, not calls that could be made.  Most code profiling tools should be able to show this.

Here's a couple of fellows looking at the call graph:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTfflRHYY80

---

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Default.aspx) will show you possible calls by analyzing assemblies and pdb files.

Comment: hmmmmm.............any other tool, Profiler needs me to navigate through the events and forms...to trace the result